# Transformation accent characters written in Tex

Tags: characters, input-encodings

I am using UTF8 encoding now and don't need to use LaTeX macros to typeset accented characters.

> Would you know an automative process to convert accent characters coded with Tex macros to utf8 characters?

In other words, i would like to convert this kind of sentence :

```
M\'ethodes directes de r\'esolution de syst\`emes lin\'eaires
```

into

```
Méthode directes de résolution de systèmes linéaires
```

Thank you for your help

P.S: Sorry for my english, don't hesitate to correct my syntax

Comment: Your editor can find and replace...

Comment: yes but it is a bit long if you have to do this for all kind of accents, it is not a exhaustive process

Comment: The source file is not related to TeX so it must be done via the editor capabilities. Search & *Replace All* would work properly.

Comment: And if you have a lot of files where you want to do replacements, a little script (python for example) would do a good job.

Comment: http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/recode/ i find this. But i didn't see how to use it

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with (La)TeX. You'll be able to use any editor for a search-and-replace, or compile your document and then copy-and-paste the UTF8 output back to your source.

Comment: @Bendesarts Any automatic solution is potentially erroneous.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `recode` which is perfect for that kind of job like so:

```
recode -d TeX..u8 file.tex
```

More information here: https://github.com/pinard/Recode/

Comment: is it unix command ? Is it possible to use it with windows ?

Comment: Maybe there: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/recode.htm

Comment: I manage to install gnuwin32. Would you know the syntax to launch recode on a file with gnuwin32 ?

Comment: @Bendesarts just open a command window and type the command shown

Comment: @Bendesarts keep in mind that `recode` will overwrite your files.  Make a backup first.

Comment: @RobertAlessi A very good advice: _Only TeX can really understand TeX code._

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, `recode` good though it may be at its job, must be used with great caution!